# How to use boost::lambda together with std::find_if?

Tags: c++

I have a std::vector and I want to check a specific attribute
of each element. SomeStruct has an attribute 'type'. I want to check this attribute
to be either Type1 or Type2.

My plan is to use boost::lambda.

```
std::vector<SomeStruct>::const_iterator it =
    std::find_if(
        vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        _1.type == SomeStruct::Type1 || _1.type == SomeStruct::Type2);
```

Because I need to access a specific attribute of each element, I'm not sure if I can
use boost::lambda at all.

Any hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::find_if(
    vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    bind(&SomeStruct::type, _1) == SomeStruct::Type1 ||
    bind(&SomeStruct::type, _1) == SomeStruct::Type2);
```

Comment: This is perfect, but I can't fathom why it works. It also works the same way if you bind(&SomeStruct::func, _1) (where func is a function) which confuses me even more.

Comment: @yhager `bind(&SomeStruct::type, _1)` gives you a boost lambda that stands for the result of doing `.type` on the object that `_1` is a placeholder for. For more information [see the documentation for bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions).

Answer (score 1):

Your expression does not compile because of

```
_1.type
```

The dot operator cannot be overloaded so your expression cannot work as a lambda expression, It's simply referring to member `type` of the object `_1` defined in boost::lambda.hpp. Well, I don't know what is `_1` type and thinking about this type makes me shudder - it's not for us, mortals to know it :-).
The proper expression is given by sepp2k.

Comment: The type of `_1` is `boost::lambda::placeholder1_type`.